# YouTube API videoEntry count comments

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get the comment count for a video entry but this is giving me a count of 1 when there are no comments. Any ideas?

```
<?php
    $commentFeed = $yt->getVideoCommentFeed($videoID);
    if ( count($commentFeed) > 0 )
    {
        foreach ($commentFeed as $commentEntry)
        {
            // print commentEntry
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the PHP version of the API (I've only used the Python one) but I am pretty sure your issue is that when you get `$commentFeed`, it is returning the full comment feed XML. This includes a root element named `<feed>` with a bunch of `<entry>` elements.

So, what you should probably be doing is checking to see if `entry` within `$commentFeed` is greater than zero or exists.

Answer (score 1):

The comments count can be accessed by:

```
$yt->getVideoCommentFeed($videoID)->totalResults->text
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bartek**, To my knowledge the commentFeed from Google only contains the most recent 25  `<entry>`.

As far as the original question, without knowledge of what the `$commentFeed` object contains, it's difficult to answer your question. My suggestion would be to `print_r($commentFeed)` and see what you are dealing with. I believe it will be something more like `count($commentFeed->entry)`